# Find highest in a group and update a column based n that

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Simplified example: My table has 4 columns: ID, Name, Amount and Parent. See image.

The parent column, in the actual table, is currently empty and needs to be populated with entries from the column "Name".

ID is a non unique column with multiple entries in the column 'Name' having the same ID.

The goal is to find the maximum value entry in the column "Amount" for any ID and populate the column "Parent" with the entry in column "Name".
I will post a picture of an example table in comments

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique is to rank names within each ID by amount in a subquery and then join it back to the source table for update:

```
update my_table set "parent"="name"
from (
    select id,"name",row_number() over (partition by id order by "amount" desc)
    from my_table
) t
where my_table.id=t.id
and t.row_number=1
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @Jasmine - Mark it as answer if it helped you

Comment: @AlexYes, thanks again. I am learning sql and would really appreciate if you could explain what is happening in the code. If you have some time that is.

Comment: @jasmine you can run the part of the statement in brackets to see what is the result of `row_number()` part, basically it builds the rank. This is called window function. Check info about window functions to learn more, this is a very useful stuff for analytics. Another part is `update from ... where` that is a typical Postgres synthax for updating the table with results of another query.